# Number of elements of order $p$ in a cyclic $p$-group.

Tags: group-theory

Allow $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ for some prime $p$. How do I show that there are $p$ elements of order $p$ in $G$?

Looking at the case of $p = 2$ is rather clear. For any $G = \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$, the elements of order $2$ will only be $0$ and $2^{n-1}$.

A possible approach I considered was examining the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{p^n} \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ by $m \mapsto m^p$. Maybe there is a simpler route. Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $p-1$ elements of order $p$, as there is one and only one subgroup of the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$ of order $p$.(Remember,  $e$ has order $1$.)

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you.